# app_id parameter in like button iframe code

Tags: html, facebook-like

I have a question about a parameter I see in the iframe URL when I generate the code for the like button. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
When I copy the iframe code, I see something like:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?
    app_id=1234567890&href&send=false&layout=standard&width=300&
    show_faces=true&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=80"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;
    width:300px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The meaning of all these parameters is clear to me, except "app_id".
What application is that?

I didn't specify any URL in the code, so why is Facebook giving me a new app_id?
Wasn't the app_id parameter supposed to be included in the OpenGraph tags?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found upon investigation:

When you generate a Like button (ie, click the "get code" button), a new Facebook application is created called "Unnamed App" and tied to your developer account.

This is undocumented and new behavior. We may be seeing the result of some un-announced Facebook Platform feature/policy. Keep your eye on [F8](http://www.facebook.com/f8) for possible details.

Comment: That's what I thought too. You're right: I can now see many "Unnamed App" (the equivalent in my language) in my Developer application. I wonder why nobody talked about this!

Comment: Anyway, does this "app_id" parameter override the og:app_id meta tag, now?

Comment: Not for the time being. You can still mark a webpage as an OG object with meta tags then running it through the URL Linter. Verify this with Insights for your OG objects. My guess is this process is very obscure and the behavior in question is a new/different approach.

Answer (score 0):

what you are coping should be the xfbml version of the like button and that require javaScript SDK.

And in order to initializee JavaScript SDK, you need to register an facebook app.
app_id is part of the information of the app that u can obtained from your registered app

Comment: It's in the iframe version too, not only in the XFBML.
That is confusing me, because I knew the app_id could be specified only in the og:app_id meta tag.
Also, I don't see this parameter documented anywhere.

Comment: the app_id is used in many places, e.g. loading the javascript sdk, initializing the php sdk etc

Comment: I know that... I created many applications that interact with Facebook, both web sites and mobile (iPhone) applications. I wonder why this parameter appeared on the like button code, now. I don't remember it was there in the past!